# Unix: most text reader and regexp

Tags: regex, unix

I usually use `most` as my favorite text reader in Unix. I know the search line in `most`, but as far as I know, it doesn't recognize any regular expressions.
How can I search regular expressions in `most`?

Comment: I found the following in the source code (in `search.c`): `/* Note!!!  The regular expression searches may not work.  I have not tested them.
 FIXME!!!  This whole thing needs to be rewritten.  It is a mess. */`... Well... meh.